# How to change string data type of specific attribute to Integer in Magento

Tags: php, magento, collections

I created an input field attribute in Magento Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes. However, Magento saves all these data as string.

Question:

Is there a way I can change the data type of that specific attribute to integer via admin dashboard?

Or

Do I need to locate the exact database table of that attribute to change it as integer?

UPDATE:
As @SimBeez mentioned that there is no way to change the data type of an attribute in admin back end.

UPDATED QUESTION:

How can I programatically update the data type of a specific attribute from string to Integer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no any way to change attribute type INT (admin panel), By default Magento store data as a string.

Comment: thanks @SimBeez for your answer. if there's no way changing that attribute. Can you give me idea on how to update the data type of that attribute. thanks!

Comment: Thanks @SimBeez. What specific tables are to be touched? Can you give me idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to touch DB instead delete your old custom attribute & make new one & while making it(from magento admin) you can select "Input Validation for Store Owner" & can select "Integer Number"